# Disable y-scrolling on element with child elements set to display: inline-block

Tags: css

Say I have a parent div and a bunch of child divs

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="child">stuff</div>
    <div class="child">stuff</div>
    <div class="child">stuff</div>
    <div class="child">stuff</div>
    <div class="child">stuff</div>
    <div class="child">stuff</div>
    etc.
</div>
```

How can I get the child divs to line up horizontally (`inline-block`) and disable the overflow-y scroll bar while forcing the child divs to continue to generate left-right?

http://jsfiddle.net/cpofvohr/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `white-space: pre` or `white-space: nowrap` to `#container` to prevent wrapping.

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cpofvohr/1/)**

```js
var div = document.getElementById("container");

for (i = 1; i < 40; i++) {
  var div2 = document.createElement("div");
  div2.className = "child";
  var text = document.createTextNode(i)
  div2.appendChild(text);
  div.appendChild(div2);
}
```

```css
.child {
  background-color: #D8D8D8;
  height: 375px;
  width: 30px;
  margin: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#container {
  width: auto;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: works in the same way if using `whitespace:nowrap` :)